# Drupal 7.18 : Avoiding duplicated contents caused by using multilanguages?

Tags: drupal

I have a project with Drupal.

- I'm using Drupal 7.18.
- I created a taxonomy called "Popularity" which has 3 elements: Popular,New,Most Rated.
- I added a second language to drupal,
- I translated my taxonomy into the second language. For ex,it is "Turkish".
- I created a Content which has field related to that taxonomy. Let's say it is "C Programming".
- I choosed "New" taxonomy item in related field.

  - After that, I translated the content that I have just created into Turkish,
- now I have two contents, but they are translated form of each other.

Anyway then, the name "New" in English content turned to "Yeni" in Turkish content.My question is, when I create a view which shows "New" or "Yeni" Contents, I see two contents in table, but I want to see only the content which has same language with the current language of website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Content: Language` filter to your view, set to `Current user's language`.